# How underline text in Inkscape without editing XML?

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way, via an extension or not, to underline text in Inkscape, without having to resort to editing the XML source?

Comment: In recent versions (1.0.1 and above), you can use the Selector and CSS dialog. See the answer here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67012/147300

Comment: @s.ouchene Indeed, that's already a tad easier than editing the XML. Thanks.